# Add another counter in the system

Tags: java, android, button, count

I've got one counter in this project its all working but I'm trying to put another counter at the bottom of the screen that will do the same but will work on another count. So there are gonna be two counters counting differently, but I can't get it to work.

**xml code:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="Count" />
```

**Main Code:**

```
package com.example.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 // Private member field to keep track of the count
 private static int mCount = 0;

private TextView countTextView;
private Button countButton;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
private SharedPreferences settings = null;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

    /** ADD THIS METHOD **/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
      countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCount);

      countButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              mCount++;
              countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
              editor = settings.edit(); 
              editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
              editor.commit();
          }
      });
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


     }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();  
      mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
      countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please show where two counters are defined?

Comment: anywhere were we have mcount and buttoncount and textviewcount

Comment: but theres currently only the one counter in here right now everything ive tried doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need threading to perform this task, each counter must run in an individual Thread.

Do something like that:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

   public void run() {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      counter++;
   }
});
t.start();
```

or use AsyncTask

**UPDATE:**

make another counter and two Thread variables:

```
private static int mCount2 = 0;
private static Thread mT1, mT2;
```

then you need a method, something like this:

```
private void startCounter(Thread t, counter) {
   t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

      public void run() {
         while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            counter++;
         }
      }
   });
t.start();
}
```

you can call this method in your onclick-method with for each thread with the counter,
then you just have to stop the Threads in the onPause method:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();  
  mT1.stop();
  mT2.stop();
}
```

maybe you need if clauses to test if the thread is acutally running.

Comment: ok how would I go about adding that into the code? *im very new to java coding*

Comment: you just need another counter variable, and then add the threading into the onClick method or, you make a method startCounter(int counter) where do the threading so that you just need to call startCounter(counter1); startCounter(counter2) inside the onClick-method

Comment: ok that made no sense to me sorry :L any chance you could add it onto the code as I have no idea x